# MLPRegressor learning_rate_init for lbfgs solver in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

For a school project I need to evaluate a neural network with different learning rates. I chose `sklearn` to implement the neural network (using the `MLPRegressor` class). Since the training data is pretty small (20 instances, 2 inputs and 1 output each) I decided to use the `lbfgs` solver, since stochastic solvers like `sgd` and `adam` for this size of data don't make sense.

The project mandates testing the neural network with different learning rates. That, however, is not possible with the `lbfgs` solver according to the documentation:

> **learning_rate_init** double, default=0.001
>   The initial learning rate used. It controls the step-size in updating the weights. Only used when solver=’sgd’ or ‘adam’.

Is there a way I can access the learning rate of the `lbfgs` solver somehow and modify it or that question doesn't even make sense?

Comment: If it's just for a school project just go for stochastic gradient descent, why do you want to use lbfgs?

Comment: Stochastic just seems like a bad choice for the 20 training data entries. If there is no other option I'll do that but it does seem to be defeating the purpose of the exercise a little bit.

Comment: I would definitely use data augmentation with those 20 examples, if possible.

Comment: @alan.elkin do you mind elaborating?

Comment: @gphilip With that dataset, your network will tend to memorize your training examples and probably wont be able to generalize to new unseen ones. I don't know what your training examples are, but if somehow you could create new synthesized examples derived from the real ones (and without loosing the core of what you are trying to extract from the inputs), it may help your network generalize better. Search "Data Augmentation" for more details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LBFGS is an optimization algorithm that **simply does not use a learning rate**. For the purpose of your school project, you should use either *sgd* or *adam*. Regarding whether it makes more sense or not, I would say that training a neural network on 20 data points doesn't make a lot of sense anyway, except for learning the basics.

LBFGS is a quasi-newton optimization method. It is based on the hypothesis that the function you seek to optimize can be approximated locally by a second order Taylor development. It roughly proceeds like this:

- Start from an initial guess
- Use the Jacobian matrix to compute the direction of steepest descent
- Use the Hessian matrix to compute the **descent step** and reach the next point
- repeat until convergence

The difference with Newton methods is that quasi Newton methods use approximates for the Jacobian and/or Hessian matrices.

Newton and quasi-newton methods requires more smoothness from the function to optimize than the gradient descent, but converge faster. Indeed, computing the descent step with the Hessian matrix is more efficient because it can foresee the distance to the local optimum, thus not ending up oscillating around it or converging very slowly. On the other side, the gradient descent only use the Jacobian matrix (first order derivatives) to compute the direction of steepest descent and use the **learning rate as the descent step**.

Practically the gradient descent is used in deep learning because computing the Hessian matrix would be too expensive.

Here it makes no sense to talk about a learning rate for Newton methods (or Quasi-Newton methods), it is just not applicable.

Comment: Thank you! This clears it up and most of it goes way over my head.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but hopefully a good pointer.

The [sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor) is implemented [multilayer_perceptron](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py#L1083) module on github.

by inspecting the module I noticed that differently from other solvers, scitkit implements the lbfgs algorithm in the Base class itself. So you can easily adapt it.

It seems that they don't use any learning rate, so you could adapt this code and multiply the loss by a learning rate you want to test. I'm just not totally sure if it makes sense adding a learning rate in the context of lbfgs.

I believe the loss if being used here:

```
        opt_res = scipy.optimize.minimize(
                self._loss_grad_lbfgs, packed_coef_inter,
                method="L-BFGS-B", jac=True,
                options={
                    "maxfun": self.max_fun,
                    "maxiter": self.max_iter,
                    "iprint": iprint,
                    "gtol": self.tol
                },
```

the code is located in line 430 of the _multilayer_perceptron.py module

```
def _fit_lbfgs(self, X, y, activations, deltas, coef_grads,
                   intercept_grads, layer_units):
        # Store meta information for the parameters
        self._coef_indptr = []
        self._intercept_indptr = []
        start = 0

        # Save sizes and indices of coefficients for faster unpacking
        for i in range(self.n_layers_ - 1):
            n_fan_in, n_fan_out = layer_units[i], layer_units[i + 1]

            end = start + (n_fan_in * n_fan_out)
            self._coef_indptr.append((start, end, (n_fan_in, n_fan_out)))
            start = end

        # Save sizes and indices of intercepts for faster unpacking
        for i in range(self.n_layers_ - 1):
            end = start + layer_units[i + 1]
            self._intercept_indptr.append((start, end))
            start = end

        # Run LBFGS
        packed_coef_inter = _pack(self.coefs_,
                                  self.intercepts_)

        if self.verbose is True or self.verbose >= 1:
            iprint = 1
        else:
            iprint = -1

        opt_res = scipy.optimize.minimize(
                self._loss_grad_lbfgs, packed_coef_inter,
                method="L-BFGS-B", jac=True,
                options={
                    "maxfun": self.max_fun,
                    "maxiter": self.max_iter,
                    "iprint": iprint,
                    "gtol": self.tol
                },
                args=(X, y, activations, deltas, coef_grads, intercept_grads))
        self.n_iter_ = _check_optimize_result("lbfgs", opt_res, self.max_iter)
        self.loss_ = opt_res.fun
        self._unpack(opt_res.x)
```

Comment: It does not male sense to talk about a learning rate while using LGBFS as it is  a [quasi newton method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Newton_method), the descent step is computed by the algorithm itself. Tweaking it would break the theoretical guarantees for the convergence of the algorithm and make it inefficient.